# Any way to declare multiple friend classes in one statement?

Tags: c++, class

I wish to declare multiple C++ friend classes in one statement as below, just to tidy the code. The reason is, in my actual application, there will be three or four friend classes, so it'll be messier than this sample.

Is it possible in any way?

```cpp
class A{
    friend class B, C; // this doesn't work
    // friend class B;
    // friend class C; // these two would be okay
};

class B{};
class C{};
```

Comment: @Remy your edit didn't let me have fun by exploiting the wording :D

Comment: Multiple *functions* can be declared in a single `friend` statement (as [shown by cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)), but I don't know if multiple *types* can be specified.

Comment: `#define FRIEND(a, b) friend class a; friend class b`

Comment: @Eljay that wouldn't be a single statement

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili • True.  But would fulfill the goal of tidying the code.  By polluting the code with macros, which are The Devil™.

Comment: @Eljay we need "fold expressions" in macros, so we can do `#define FRIEND(...) friend class __VA_ARGS__ ...;`

Comment: I would even want variadic `friend` notation :-/ (not MACRO)

Comment: @Jarod42 we should sign a petition to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037062/any-way-to-declare-multiple-friend-classes-in-one-statement#comment120253734_68037062) into the language.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili • as long as we can get `using std::{cout, cin, ostream, string};` in the language too!

Comment: @Eljay once we have the fold macros, you can do `#define USING(nspace, ...) using nspace:: __VA_ARGS__ ...;`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I'm for less MACRO though...

Comment: @Jarod42 I was just joking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you need to write it out longhand.

I can't think of a grammatical reason why your notation couldn't be introduced. (C++17 allows you to shorten the namespace notation, for example, so you're idea is not without precedent).

Why don't you propose your idea to the C++ standards committee?

Of course there will be counter-arguments centred around compiler complexity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll try to propose it.

Comment: @Kaz Do study how such proposals are submitted first though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Whole classes - you can't, as friend declaration in that case also acts like forward declaration and that would be conflicting syntax.

But you can declare members of various classes as friends in one statement, if those are already complete:

```
#include "class_b.h"
#include "class_c.h"

class A {
   friend B::B(), C::~C();
};
```